# Client can't interact with WCF-service when it is hosted by accoreconsole.exe

Tags: c#, wcf, autocad

Windows 7 x64
Visual Studio 2015 Update 1
AutoCAD 2016 SP1 x64
.Net Framework 4.6.1

I have a problem when my WCF service is hosted by `accoreconsole.exe` instead of `acad.exe`: the client application (the console application) can't interact with it. Both cases servise was opened successfully and `telnet` works fine with the necessary port. I use HTTP protocol. I haven't this problem when the host is `acad.exe` (for the same client application).

For this problem demonstration I created [the simple solution](https://bitbucket.org/Andrey-Bushman/sandboxcad) with two projects: client and service. Detailed info about each of them is discribed in their `readme.md` files. The problem with screens is described in the `readme.md` of the solution.

### NOTE

It is necessary to read `readme.md` files, because they contain important info. For building this solution you are to launch Visual Studio with admin rights.

I will be very grateful for the explanation of the reasons of this problem.

Best regards, Andrey.

### UPD 1

I got [the logs](https://yadi.sk/d/xZYNBxw8qtw8m) from the client and service for both cases of hosting: through the `acad.exe` (working case) and `accoreconsole.exe` (the problem case). I am learning it now through the *Microsoft Service Trace Viewer* (GUI application).

Comment: when you open the accoreconsole.exe on your context, does it stay open? on most cases, it will open, run your script, then close, therefore the service will end.

Comment: You are using a virtual connection which is using an Ethernet port to communicate.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to view the actual communications.  I would compare the working application against the non working application.  I would check the http headers is the data messages to see the differences in the working application with the non-working application.

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves, it is opened. https://bitbucket.org/Andrey-Bushman/sandboxcad/src/2b8249042c300314d4bc0e95bdfae4b88022dd6f/MyServices/ExtensionApplication.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: @jdweng I nothing know about it. :( I would like to use WCF.

Comment: @AndreyBushman, when running your code, open the "Task Manager" to make sure accoreconsole.exe is, in fact, running as you say. Also, as far as I remember trying, accoreconsole.exe doesn't accept new calls (from automation) after is open (but I haven't tried with WCF). Acad.exe is a little different...

Comment: I didn't understand you about the "Task Manager". What does mean "running as you say" phrase?

Comment: Use sniffer just for debugging.

Comment: @AndreyBushman He means, open the [Windows Task Manager](http://i.imgur.com/Nt2PP.png) and verify that `accoreconsole.exe` is listed. If `accoreconsole.exe` crashes and closes then obviously you cannot interact with it.

Comment: Of course it is listed.:) `accoreconsole.exe` is not crashed, also I see its window. You would  see it on the screens if you would open the link which I pointed in the theme...

Comment: my point was: I don't believe accoreconsole will remain receiving calls after it was launched, it was designed to launch with a list of commands on the .scr file. If you maintain the instance running, you loose the benefit of memory management that you gain launching one instance for each task.

Comment: I understand, but the tasks can be various. I still want to solve the problem with WCF service hosting inside of `accoreconsole.exe`...

Comment: I think the point @AugustoGoncalves is making is that the CoreConsole.exe should not live forever and dispatch the AutoCAD jobs, it should work on one single AutoCAD-related task, provide a result and then terminate. There should be a separate host application to oversee all of the units of work sent to the CoreConsole instances.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to so with the way they ruined `stdout` when they broke CoreConsole after version 2013 ?

Comment: Service `srv1` works on remote computer. It can be self-hosted or hosted by `IIS` or `WAS`. When `srv1` gets a task (from any local or remote client application) it launches the `accoreconsole.exe` which is the host of `srv2` service (console window is hidden). The `srv1` also is the client of the `srv2` service. The `srv1` sends the task to `srv2` service and recives the result of the task. Then `srv1` sends the result to remote client application and closes the `accoreconsole.exe`.

Comment: The `accoreconsole.exe` by Autodesk is written through the bum. It has many bugs still. For example: http://bushman-andrey.blogspot.ru/2016/04/accoreconsole.html

Comment: I added the *UPD1* section.

Comment: through the bum. yup, I got this one today: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-2013-2014-2015-2016-2017/error-53-when-trying-to-open-accoreconsole/m-p/5839101/highlight/false#M97697

Comment: and this old favorite: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/accoreconsole-exe-in-2015-doesn-t-do-system-console-writeline/m-p/5539352#M43603

Comment: Autodesk slogan: `accoreconsole.exe`- we'll do the work with it through ass. It seems to me the problem can't be solved. :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... This problem is exists for AutoCAD 2016 only. With AutoCAD 2013-2015 I have not this problem. So... `accoreconsole.exe` of AutoCAD 2016 is written through the ass...

It is possible the same problem will be in newer AutoCAD versions too (AutoCAD 2017 for example)... But I haven't AutoCAD 2017 and therefore I can't check it.